# SQLITE Query- To retrieve all versions between two versions?

Tags: sql, python-3.x, sqlite, version

The sqlite table consists of attributes :

```
|Versions (TEXT)|
| "2.73.8"      | 
| "3.6.4 "      | 
| "3.9.11"      |
```

and so on..

I want to retrieve all the versions from the table between two versions given  in the query. For instance: Between versions- 2.9.10 & 3.7.10 .

I could not find any sqlite function to query this directly. I used Substring (SUBSTR) to split to get individual digits which could then be compared to the one present in the table. I was successful in doing that but I could find a way to query to retrieve all versions between two version set.

```
create table prod(version varchar);

insert into prod values('2.7.5');
insert into prod values('2.7.4');
insert into prod values('2.0.0');
insert into prod values('22.73.55');
insert into prod values('22.17.54');
insert into prod values('22.10.06');
insert into prod values('3.7.5');
insert into prod values('3.4.5');
insert into prod values('3.7.6');
```

Query to retrieve all versions below or equal to : "3.50.6" (using nested "case when" ):

---

```
SELECT * from prod
Where version IN ( SELECT 
    CASE WHEN (CAST(substr(version,0,instr(version,'.')) as integer)=3)
         THEN 
            CASE WHEN (cast(SUBSTR(SUBSTR(version, INSTR(version, '.')),1,INSTR(SUBSTR(version, INSTR(version, '.') + 1), '.') - 1) as float)< 0.50 )
                 THEN
                    version
                 ELSE
                    CASE WHEN (cast(SUBSTR(SUBSTR(version, INSTR(version, '.')),1,INSTR(SUBSTR(version, INSTR(version, '.') + 1), '.') - 1) as float)=0.50)
                         THEN
                             CASE WHEN (CAST(replace(version, rtrim(version, replace(version, '.', '')), '')AS INTEGER)<=6)
                                  THEN version

END  END END END FROM prod);
```

---

Kindly provide me a way to query to retrieve all versions in the table  between two sets of versions.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the following will do as you want :-

```
WITH 
  /* SELECTION parameters */
  parm(p1,p2) AS (SELECT '3.4.5', '22.10.6' /*<<<<<<<<<<<<< Versions to check against lower first*/),
    /* Parse 1, 1st value of each and the rest for parse2 */
    pv1(parmv1,rest4p2,parm2v1,rest4p22) AS (
        SELECT 
            CAST(substr(p1,1,instr(p1,'.')-1) AS INTEGER),
            substr(p1,instr(p1,'.')+1), 
            CAST(substr(p2,1,instr(p2,'.')-1) AS INTEGER),
          substr(p2,instr(p2,'.')+1)    
        FROM parm
        ),
    /* Parse 2 extra 2 values retrieved for each parameter */
    pv2(parmv2,parmv3,parm2v2,parm2v3) AS (
        SELECT 
            CAST(substr(rest4p2,1,instr(rest4p2,'.')-1) AS INTEGER),
            CAST(substr(rest4p2,instr(rest4p2,'.')+1) AS INTEGER),
            CAST(substr(rest4p22,1,instr(rest4p22,'.')-1) AS INTEGER),
            CAST(substr(rest4p22,instr(rest4p22,'.')+1) AS INTEGER)
    FROM pv1),
    /* calculate the lower and upper values to be checked against for the BETWEEN clause */
    finalp(lower,higher) AS (
        SELECT 
            (parmv1 * 1000 * 1000) + (SELECT (parmv2 * 1000) + parmv3 FROM pv2),
            (parm2v1 * 1000 * 1000) + (SELECT (parm2v2 * 1000) + parm2v3 FROM pv2) 
        FROM pv1),

    /* Parse 1 for the actual data gets the 1st part of the version and the rest of the version */  
    v1(v1rowid,vpart1,rest4v2) AS (SELECT rowid, CAST(substr(version,1,instr(version,'.')-1) AS INTEGER),substr(version,instr(version,'.')+1)  FROM prod),
    /* Parse 2 for the actual data gets the 2nd and third parts */
    v2(v2rowid,vpart2,vpart3) AS (SELECT v1rowid, CAST(substr(rest4v2,1,instr(rest4v2,'.')+1) AS INTEGER),CAST(substr(rest4v2,instr(rest4v2,'.')+1) AS INTEGER) FROM v1)

SELECT version
FROM v1 
    JOIN v2 ON v1rowid = v2rowid /* join the 2nd and third parts with the 1st */
    JOIN prod ON prod.rowid = v1rowid /* also join the original data for the original version */ 
    JOIN finalp ON 1 = 1 /* joint the upper and lower values */
WHERE 
    (vpart1 * 1000 * 1000) + (vpart2 * 1000) + vpart3 /* do the same calculation used for the upper and lower parameters */ 
    BETWEEN lower AND higher
;
```

The above results in :-

[image]

and using :-

```
.... (SELECT '3.4.5', '22.10.06' /*<<<<<<<<<<<<< Versions to check against lower first*/) ...
```

as well as :-

```
.... (SELECT '3.4.5', '22.10.6' /*<<<<<<<<<<<<< Versions to check against lower first*/) ....
```

- **`.6`** instead of **`.06`** (i.e. leading 0's are ignored)

Results in :-

[image]

- This also checks boundary hits i.e. 3.4.5 and 20.10.06 were selected.

Comment: How should I include this query inside the c.execute() when using python library "sqlite" . Also how to take input of two versions as variables to this query ?

Comment: unfortunately the "with" is not supported by the sqlite version that comes with python2.7 and due to other dependencies I have to stick with that version. So can you provide an alternative to your solution that doesn't use "with". I appreciate your effort.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that each one of the 3 parts of the version value is max 3 digits.
The simplest way to convert a version value to a number so to make it comparable, is : multiply the 1st part by 1000000, the 2nd part by 1000 and then add them plus the 3d part.
In code:

```
1000000 * replace(version, '.', 'x') +
1000 * replace(substr(version, instr(version, '.') + 1), '.', 'x') +
replace(version, '.', '000') % 1000 number
```

If you execute:

```
select 
  version,
  1000000 * replace(version, '.', 'x') +
  1000 * replace(substr(version, instr(version, '.') + 1), '.', 'x') +
  replace(version, '.', '000') % 1000 numericversion
from prod
```

you get:

```
| version  | numericversion  |
| -------- | --------------  |
| 2.7.5    |  2007005        |
| 2.7.4    |  2007004        |
| 2.0.0    |  2000000        |
| 22.73.55 | 22073055        |
| 22.17.54 | 22017054        |
| 22.10.06 | 22010006        |
| 3.7.5    |  3007005        |
| 3.4.5    |  3004005        |
| 3.7.6    |  3007006        |
```

So to get all versions between versions- 2.9.10 & 3.7.10, do this:

```
with 
  cte1 as (
    select
      1000000 * replace('2.9.10', '.', 'x') +
      1000 * replace(substr('2.9.10', instr('2.9.10', '.') + 1), '.', 'x') +
      replace('2.9.10', '.', '000') % 1000 numericversion  
  ),
  cte2 as (
    select
      1000000 * replace('3.7.10', '.', 'x') +
      1000 * replace(substr('3.7.10', instr('3.7.10', '.') + 1), '.', 'x') +
      replace('3.7.10', '.', '000') % 1000 numericversion  
  ),
  versions as (
    select 
      version, 
      1000000 * replace(version, '.', 'x') +
      1000 * replace(substr(version, instr(version, '.') + 1), '.', 'x') +
      replace(version, '.', '000') % 1000 numericversion
    from prod  
  )  
select version from versions
where numericversion between 
  (select numericversion from cte1) and (select numericversion from cte2)
```

The 1st CTE returns the numeric value of `2.9.10`, the 2nd CTE returns the numeric value of `3.7.10` and the 3d the numeric values of all the versions in the table.
Finally the query compares the numeric versions.
See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/spJHBDcN8r3GJAUF12NuqF/1).
Results:

```
| version |
| ------- |
| 3.7.5   |
| 3.4.5   |
| 3.7.6   |
```

Or without the CTEs by hardcoding the 2 versions as numbers:

```
select version from prod
where 
  1000000 * replace(version, '.', 'x') +
  1000 * replace(substr(version, instr(version, '.') + 1), '.', 'x') +
  replace(version, '.', '000') % 1000 
  between 2009010 and 3007010
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/spJHBDcN8r3GJAUF12NuqF/3).
Or:

```
select version from prod
where 
  1000000 * replace(version, '.', 'x') +
  1000 * replace(substr(version, instr(version, '.') + 1), '.', 'x') +
  replace(version, '.', '000') % 1000 
  between 
    1000000 * replace('2.9.10', '.', 'x') +
    1000 * replace(substr('2.9.10', instr('2.9.10', '.') + 1), '.', 'x') +
    replace('2.9.10', '.', '000') % 1000
    and
    1000000 * replace('3.7.10', '.', 'x') +
    1000 * replace(substr('3.7.10', instr('3.7.10', '.') + 1), '.', 'x') +
    replace('3.7.10', '.', '000') % 1000
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/spJHBDcN8r3GJAUF12NuqF/5).

Comment: How should I include this query inside the c.execute() when using python library "sqlite" . Also how to take input of two versions as variables to this query ?

Comment: unfortunately the "with" is not supported by the sqlite version that comes with python2.7 and due to other dependencies I have to stick with that version. So can you provide an alternative to your solution that doesn't use "with". I appreciate your effort.

Comment: The last query does not use with.

Comment: true,but i want to pass variables as version numbers in the query,in order to the enable query to run for any set of versions given.

Comment: I am unsure of adding version numbers as variables in the query. I have to add variables V1 and V2 here in place of '2.9.10' and '3.7.10' respectively. I used '?' it worked only for one occurance.

Comment: I can't help you with Python. My answer is about SQLite.

Comment: how to modify the query to just retrieve the "between version values" if  the version contained in the table is not greater than the end version. For eg: if a table has version values: (3.4.7 , 4.6.9, 6.2.6 , 7.3.6 ) and the version to look for is :start_version = 4.0.0 and end_version = 7.0.0 . In this case it should not retrieve (4.6.9 , 6,2.6 ) as the table has ( 7.3.6 ) which is greater than  end_version = 7.0.0 .

Comment: I am trying to use CASE WHEN statements but i am not successful as I want to retrieve more than one column form the table. Is there a way around this?

Comment: Is there a better way out for this other than CASE statements, by modifying the earlier post of the query ?